# Jquery position().left Как быть на мобильниках?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

На мобильных устройствах, если зумишь экран, position всегда разный.

```
 $('g[sid="25"]').position().left
```

Как сделать так, чтобы он не менял свои значения?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно стоит использовать `.offset()`

`.offset()` - координаты относительно начала страницы.

`.position()` - относительно ближайшего родителя с заданным позиционированием.

*Важно отметить, что используя метод .offset() вы получите позицию только первого элемента из всех выбранных. Если вам нужны значения координат всех элементов, то следует использовать конструкции типа .map() или .each().*

[Источник](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0)